# Gradient of a function in multi-variate calculus please help

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the gradient of the function at the given point. 
$g(x, y) = 3xe^{y/x}$, at point $(3, 0)$.

How do you compute the gradient of this function. Please help me.

Comment: I suggest a logarithmic differentiation approach here. Take the log of both sides, then compute $\frac{\partial\log g}{\partial x}$ and same for $y$. This kind of function can't be differentiated using the standard properties because $x^x$ doesn't follow any of the patterns we establish early on in a calculus course. Hence we use logarithmic differentiation.

Comment: i am still lost. what do you mean?

Comment: I'll do part of it in the answer below.

Comment: Alternatively, write $y^{x/y}=\exp(\ln(y^{x/y}))=\exp(x\ln(y)/y)$. Do you know how to differentiate this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Initially OP wrote $g(x,y) = 3xy^{\frac{y}{x}}$ but realized it was incorrect. I have left the initial work for posterity. The actual answer is given in the edit.* As per my comment above, we want to take the logarithm of $g$ as standard calculus identities do not apply to this function. Doing so we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \log g &=& \log(3xy^{\frac{y}{x}}) \\ &=& \log(3x) + \frac{y}{x}\log(y). \end{eqnarray} $$

Differentiating this with respect to $x$ gives:

$$\frac{\partial\log g}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{y}{x^2}\log(y).$$

Multiplying both sides of this by $g$, we get that

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 3xy^{\frac{y}{x}}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2}\log(y)\right). $$

Do you see how to do this for $y$? Knowing these two, do you see how to get the gradient?

**Edit**: Since the actual definition of $g$ is $g(x,y) = 3x\exp\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$, I will use standard calculus techniques.

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(3x\exp\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right) = 3\exp\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + 3x\exp\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\left(-\frac{y}{x^2}\right).$$

Above I used product rule to differentiate the separate functions of $x$ and then used chain rule on the exponential. Knowing this, do you see how to get $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$?

Comment: so the answer is (3,3)?

Comment: @jainsmit Is the point you're evaluating at supposed to be $(3,1)$ not $(3,0)$? Otherwise your derivative on $y$ diverges. If it is supposed to be $(3,1)$, then yes you are correct.

Comment: no at (3, 0) is right

Comment: @jainsmit, did you get $3y^{\frac{y}{x}}(\log(y)+1)$ for $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$?

Comment: yes I did get that

Comment: @jainsmit, as you take the limit that $y\rightarrow 0^+$, this will diverge because $\log(y)\rightarrow-\infty$.

Comment: so y will equal 0?

Comment: I think it should be that the gradient does not exist because you have $(3,-\infty)$ for the gradient, effectively.

Comment: well the only options I have is (3, -3)

Comment: (3, 0) or (0, 3) or (3, 3) or (-3, 3)

Comment: I'm inclined to think that there is a mistake in the question then and they meant to ask for $(3,1)$. So you were probably right. Clearly the $x$ component is $3$ so you only have three options to choose from.

Comment: i just reliesed i typed the problem wrong it is 3xe^(y/x)

Comment: Oh. Well that makes things much simpler. You can do logarithmic differentiation if you want but it's not necessary here. I'll change my answer to reflect the proper definition for $g$.

Comment: I edited the answer. Take a look.

Comment: you still have y in the equation. im still lost

Comment: See the edit at the bottom. I just left the stuff from before for posterity. It's frowned upon to completely rewrite your answer around here.

Comment: Ok I see what you are talking about but you did not write it as 3xe^(y/x) you used g(x,y)=3x exp(y/x)

Comment: Yeah. I prefer $\exp$ to $e$ but it's the same thing. I just like having my lines of LaTeX code be small and not take up a lot of room (like would happen with $e$ to a power).

Comment: so for y would it be 3xe^(y/x)*(1/x)

Comment: You're exactly right.

Comment: so then i got the answer as (3, 3)

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Take the partial with respect to $x$ using the product and chain rules:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}3xe^{y/x}
&=3e^{y/x}+3x\left(-\frac{y}{x^2}\right)e^{y/x}\\
&=3\frac{x-y}{x}e^{y/x}
\end{align}
$$
Take the partial with respect to $y$ using the chain rule
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}3xe^{y/x}
&=3x\left(\frac1x\right)e^{y/x}\\
&=3e^{y/x}
\end{align}
$$
The gradient of $g(x,y)$ is $\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x},\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)$. Therefore,
$$
\nabla3xe^{y/x}=\frac3xe^{y/x}(x-y,x)
$$
Plugging in $(x,y)=(3,0)$ gives $\nabla g(3,0)=(3,3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is <3,3>. $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 3e^{y/x}$.

Comment: That is not the correct partial derivative for $x$. I think you meant $y$.

Comment: @KenM: Welcome to MSE! Although you have the correct answer $<3, 3>$, it would help to provide the details of how you arrived at that. What you show as the partial is misleading and this answer would be helped by those further details. Just some friendly advice. Regards

Comment: This is not an answer. The question was "how do you compute the gradient", not "what is the gradient". Although you got the correct gradient at $(3,0)$, it is not clear your method was correct since you gave an incorrect $\partial g/\partial x$.